# Show that there exists an algorithm that computes a BFS tree from each node up to depth d in $O(d + \Delta^d)$ rounds.Its allowed to give random algo.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

English: Let G be a graph with maximum node degree $\Delta$. Show that there exists an algorithm that computes a BFS tree from each node up to depth d in $O(d + \Delta^d)$ rounds.
Remark: You are allowed to give a randomized algorithm at the cost of an extra $(log_n)$-factor in the running time. However, we believe that the most straightforward solution uses a deterministic algorithm.

Anyone has idea how to solve this Problem? And can give maybe some advice to me. Because i spend already more days on this question, but actually i dont have any approach to this exercises...

Comment: Does _each node_ actually mean _any node_? If yes, what would be the time complexity of the BFS that you limit to depth $d$?

Comment: hm, i am not sure but i think for any node.I think the time complexity should be $O(b^d)$ if we go the shallowest Node, where b is node at every state.